# Terraform in AWS - How to begin

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Not sure if this is silly or obvious, so imagine this situation. You have AWS environments including a shared services vpc, within this VPC you want your IAC resources to live - ie EC2 Instance running terraform and another say Ansible.

So if you want to have Terraform managing all your AWS infra configuration - how do you build the shared services VPC? If you are planning on hosting Terraform in there? Do you spin this up from another device running terraform and the code for the shared services vpc?

To me its a bit chicken and egg - does anyone do this already or are you letting people run local copies of Terraform?

This maybe obvious - but just interested if anyone has experienced this and what they way around it was?

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: You don't need Terraform to be run in an EC2 instance. It is just a tool to provision infrastructure, so you run Terraform from your local, and your AWS infra is "created". If you want to run Terraform from an EC2 instance, obviously, first you need to create it manually, I wouldn't know a use-case where you need that though

Comment: Thanks Hector - I did wonder if I was looking at this from the wrong angle. Just trying to keep things all in the same place on one box so I don't have to worry about versions of terraform people are using or provider versions - will just look at this from another angel now

Comment: Cool, another option would be using Vagrant, so you can run a virtual machine from a template in less than 10 seconds with all the tools you need installed (terraform, ansible, etc...) https://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: Building on the previous comments, you can also use a Continuous Integration pipeline, and run the terraform scripts from a docker container there.

Comment: Thanks Hector, Rafael - I think those are some really good idea's, going to have to spend sometime looking at those